# Is there any elegant way to make dot product between a one row matrix and each row of a more than one row matrix?

Tags: python

Is there any elegant way to make dot product between a one-row matrix and each row of a two or more row matrix in python? I am using list or list of list to represent the matrix.

Comment: Can you give an example of an input and your desired output?

Comment: check out scipy

Comment: Please read this [how-to-ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to improve your question.

Answer (score 3):

If `A` is an n×m matrix (n rows, each containing m entries), and `v` is a row vector of m entries, then the "dot product between the row vector and each row of a two or more row matrix" is usually called the matrix-vector product between `A` and `v.T` (the transpose of `v`, that is, a column vector).

With Numpy, this is simply `np.dot(A, np.reshape(v, (-1, 1)))`. In plain Python, you could write something like:

```
def inner_product(u, v):
    'Inner product between two numeric arrays.'
    return sum(x*y for x, y in zip(u, v))

def mat_vec_product(a, v):
    'Dot product between matrix `a` and column vector `v`.'
    return [inner_product(u, v) for u in a]

>>> mat = [
...     [0, 0, 0],
...     [0, 0, 1],
...     [0, 1, 0],
...     [0, 1, 1],
...     [1, 0, 0],
...     [1, 0, 1],
... ]
>>> row = [100, 20, 3]
>>> print(mat_vec_product(mat, row))
[0, 3, 20, 23, 100, 103]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `cdist` from `scipy` with custom distance function which is dot product in this case. In this case, you have to convert list of list into numpy array first.

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.spatial.distance import cdist

x1 = np.atleast_2d(np.array([1, 2, 3]))
x2 = np.array([[1,2,3], 
               [2,3,4], 
               [4,5,6]])
D = cdist(x1, x2, lambda u, v: np.dot(u.T, v))
D.ravel()
```

**Output**

```
array([ 14.,  20.,  32.])
```

Or it can be a simple matrix trick e.g. `D = x1.dot(x2.T)` (output is the same i.e. `array([ 14.,  20.,  32.])`)